# Android: MyLocationOverlay that only uses GPS

Tags: android, gps

Is it somehow possible to tell the [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) that it should only consider GPS as `LocationProvider`?

The reference says: `enableMyLocation()` => Attempts to enable `MyLocation`, registering for updates from `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` and `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

But I need only the `GPS_PROVIDER`.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a method to turn this off. However you can:

1. Override onLocationChanged and look at location.getProvider(), ignoring updates that aren't from GPS - although I'm guessing this will still draw your location from the network provider if it needs too.
2. MyLocationOverlay implements LocationListener, meaning enableLocation probably requests updates using itself with the location manager - you could instead call requestLocationUpdates with your own [Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html). However, Google Maps isn't open source, so there might be some flags or such that enableLocation also updates.. if you knew what it done, you could probably replicate it with reflection..
3. 'Turn off' the network provider using [TestProviderEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) which requires the mock location permission + that option to be enabled on the device.

Comment: ok thx. so probably it's the best solution not to use the MyLocationOverlay class, but implement everything on my own by using LocationListener. In fact i anyway just wanted to use the MyLocationOverlay  because it looked like a "fast" solution.

Comment: It is a very quick solution, but why do you not want the network provider? It'll return a fix quicker than GPS, and when the GPS comes in, it'll update to the more accurate (I guess in some situations the network can be more accurate than the gps...)